# One line to replace values with their row indices?

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0],
              [0,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1]])
```

I would like to replace every positive elements of this array by its row `index+1`. So the final result would be:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0],
              [0,2,0,0,0],
              [0,0,3,0,3]])
```

Can I do this with a simply numpy command (without looping)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.arange`

```
(a != 0) * np.reshape(np.arange(a.shape[0])+1, (-1, 1))
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 3.]])
```

Works on any array:

```
a2 = np.array([[1,0,0,-1,0],
               [0,20,0,0,0],
               [0,0,-300,0,30]])
(a2 != 0) * np.reshape(np.arange(a2.shape[0])+1, (-1, 1))
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 3.]])
```

Comment: A particular reason to use `nan_to_num(a/a)` and not `(a != 0)`?

Comment: @tobias_k lol how can i missed it. Thx for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the proper `numpy` way, but you could use `enumerate` and multiply the sub-arrays by their indices:

```
>>> np.array([x * i for i, x in enumerate(a, start=1)])
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 3]])
```

Note that this only works properly if "every positive element" is actually `1`, as in your example, and if there are no negative elements. Alternatively, you can use `a > 0` to first get an array with `True` (i.e. `1`) in every place where `a` is `> 0` and `False` (i.e. `0`) otherwise.

```
>>> a = np.array([[ 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
...               [ 0, 3, 0, 0,-8],
,,,               [-3, 0, 4, 0, 5]])
...
>>> np.array([x * i for i, x in enumerate(a > 0, start=1)])
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 3]])
```